# Referencing logged user and node relations.

Tags: rules, navigation, entities

I am trying to solve a problem with no luck:

I have 4 objects in Drupal:

- -Company user (role company)
- -Mod user (role moderator)
- -Node Project
- -Node Person (not a user entity)

Company user can add/edit/delete own Project nodes.
Mod user can a/e/d  own Person nodes.

I would love to accomplish next:

Mod can reference (add) Persons to Projects. 
Example : Person A, Person B,... (both owned by Mod1 user) can be referenced (added) to Project 1, Project 2, etc. (or unreferenced/removed).

I imagine this as M:N relation, with two extra attributes - status (value 0-5) and author/createdBy (logged Mod1 user) to prevent mod users from editing/viewing others relation entities.

Next level is creating this by Rules module and Rules link module.

Lets have a View with Projects

- clicking on a project should display a project page with list of
  referenced and unreferenced Persons owned by logged-in Mod user.
- Persons list should be clickable (rules link) for adding/removing reference
  from actualy displayed project.

I had some progress with field collection module - was able to create relation entities with status, but cannot made it with Rules - dont know how to send two parameters in rule link (project id, person id) and create project page with persons lists (maybe as view blocks with contextual filters?)

Thank for any help, or idea.

Answer (score 0):

I dont use Rules Link alot, I have used Rules Link Event and Rules. Anyways this issue queue item for Rules Link describes how to setup Parameters for a Rules Link:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1926196

From the issue:

> For your example, add the product sku field to your view and pass the
>   token for that in the views rules link field settings under:
>   Additional parameters for the rules link
>
> Edit the rules link component, click the configure rules tab, under
>   settings, add the additional parameter. I assume it could be string,
>   integer or whatever that matches your sku. The view is going to pass
>   that parameter as a variable to use in the rules link component rules
>   so you can do whatever you want with it from there.

The issue queue explains adding 1 parameter. but it does sound like it supports additional parameters to send to Rules, so just assure your View is passing 2 parameters instead of just the 1 in the *Additional Parameters*.